# How to search in parent entity scope when using spring boot data rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

Now I know how to findBySomething on root level entity.

Let's say I have a one to many relation of `class -> student`

I can now `students/search/findByName?name=Tom`

But it will give me Tom in all classes. Can I do something like

`classes/1/students/search/findByName?name=Tom`

It gives error right now.

Comment: without looking at your code it is hard to tell whats wrong with it neither able to give any helpful answer

Comment: Ah, that search is pretty much shipped with data rest. There is no implementation needed. Also I feel the data rest is limited. So I decided to not use it and removed it from my dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in StudentController

```
@GetMapping("/classes/{classId}/students/search/findByName")
public ResponseEntity<?> findStudent(@PathParam("name") String name,
                    @PathVariable("classId") String classId) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(studentService.findByNameAndClassId(name, classId));
}
```

in StudentService

```
public List<Student> findByNameAndClassId(String name, String classId) {
    return studentRepository.findByNameAndClassId(name, classId);
}
```

in StudentRepository     (I use mongoDB; if u use SQL , extends JpaRepository)

```
@Repository
public interface CustomUserRepo extends MongoRepository<Student, String> {
    List<Student> findByNameAndClassId(String name, String classId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand,
You need to access the parent entity,

It can be easily achieved using HQL queries, please look below code.

```
    @Query("select student from Student student where student.professor = ?1")
    List<String> getProfessors(String[] professors);
```

I hope, it helps!